# Javascript not calling function because syntax error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

In C# i am creating string for design of div and in which i am calling javascript function and latter appening it to div.

In c# i have done as below:

```
innerHTML.Append(@"<div  onmouseover=""javascript:ShowColor('" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["sku"]) + @"');""  class='thumbnail slide'><a   onclick='window.open('" + link + "',''_self'')' ><img src='http://www.DimpleChild.com/Images/" + dt.Rows[i]["Image"].ToString().Trim() + ".jpg' height='50' width='50'></a><span style='font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;'>$" + Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["price"]) + "</span></div>");
```

Here there is anchor tag as:

```
<a   onclick='window.open('" + link + "',''_self'')' >
```

here window.open is not getting called becase some syntax problems.

When i do `inspect element` in chrome :

```
<a onclick="window.open("www.sitename.com/sku="" 120pbootcat11',''_self'')'="">
```

How can i format it in C# so that it views correctly.???

**EDIT 1**

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes to delimit the attribute, you need to use double quotes inside it. If you use double quotes to delimit the attribute, you need to use single quotes inside it.

Try this:

```
innerHTML.Append(@"<div onmouseover=""javascript:ShowColor('" + 
     Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["sku"]) + 
     @"');"" class='thumbnail slide'><a onclick=""window.open('" + 
     link + 
     @"', '_self')"" ><img src='http://www.DimpleChild.com/Images/" + 
     dt.Rows[i]["Image"].ToString().Trim() + 
     @".jpg' height='50' width='50'></a><span style='font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;'>$" + 
     Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["price"]) + 
     @"</span></div>");
```

On the other hand, I would strongly suggest putting values in `data-...` attributes and setting up your script events in a script file, and using classes + a CSS file instead of `style` attributes. This is just hideous.

Comment: @CuteChild You need an `@` before the `",', '_self''...` part. Please try my latest code.

Answer (score 1):

You have currently written

```
<a   onclick='window.open('" + link + "',''_self'')' >
```

The problem with that is that you're terminating the quotation mark you started before `window` so a complete string is `'window.open('`.

You can solve the problem in many ways. One way is here

```
<a   onclick='window.open(\"" + link + "\",'_self')' >
```

I am putting double quotes inside the generated string so that it doesn't terminate the single-quote string you started earlier. I'm also escaping it with a `\` so that it doesn't terminate the double-quote string I started in C#. Woosh, it's complicated, I know.

Another easier way is to use the `String.Format()` function in C#.

You can write the above code as

```
var generatedHTML = String.Format("<div  onmouseover='javascript:ShowColor(\"{0}\");'  class='thumbnail slide'><a   onclick='window.open(\"{1}\",\"_self\")' ><img src='http://www.DimpleChild.com/Images/{2}.jpg' height='50' width='50'></a><span style='font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;'>${3}</span></div>", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["sku"]), link, dt.Rows[i]["Image"].ToString().Trim(), Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["price"]));

innerHTML.Append(generatedHTML);
```

I think a MUCH easier way for you to generate clean HTML/Javascript code from C# is to use a template engine like Razor. It is preconfigured in new ASP.NET projects and it can even be used standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `String.Format` for such long strings.
Also be consistent with your usage of `"` and `'`.
I always prefer using `"` for HTML attributes and `'` for javascript strings.

This is how it would look like with a String.Format:

```
innerHtml.Append(
    String.Format(
        @"<div onmouseover=""javascript:ShowColor('{0}');"" class=""thumbnail slide"">
            <a onclick=""window.open('{1}','_self')"" >
                <img src=""http://www.DimpleChild.com/Images/{2}.jpg"" height=""50"" width=""50"">
            </a>
            <span style=""font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"">${3}</span>
        </div>"
        , dt.Rows[i]["sku"].ToString()
        , link
        , dt.Rows[i]["Image"].ToString().Trim()
        , dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString()
    )
);
```

I'd say this is much more readable and quote errors won't happen to often.
In HTML it will look like:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http.//example.com/', '_self')"></a>
```